# MySQL subquery select first row for each group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I need to create a MySQL stored procedure it selects each `User` `SUM` of all the `Points` they've earned.

The query should group `Game` by `StartTime` and only select the first row of each group ordered by `Points`. I'm trying to ignore duplicate `StartTime` values for each `User` but still keep the first one. This should avoid cheating if the `User` saves the same game twice.

If the `User` hasn't been in any `Game`, it should still return `NULL`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetPoints`(
    IN _StartDate DATETIME,
    IN _EndDate DATETIME,
    IN _Limit INT,
    IN _Offset INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT `User`.`UserId`, `User`.`Username`,
        (SELECT SUM(`Game`.`Points`)
            FROM `Game`
            WHERE `Game`.`UserId` = `User`.`UserId` AND
            `Game`.`StartDate` > _StartDate AND `Game`.`StartDate` < _EndDate
            GROUP BY `Game`.`StartDate`
            ORDER BY `Game`.`Points` DESC
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS `Value`
    FROM `User`
    ORDER BY `Value` DESC, `User`.`Username` ASC
    LIMIT _Limit OFFSET _Offset;
END
```

Sample User Table

```
+--------+----------+
| UserId | Username |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | JaneDoe  |
|      2 | JohnDoe  |
+--------+----------+
```

Sample Game Table

```
+--------+--------+-------------------------+--------+
| GameId | UserId |        StartDate        | Points |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+--------+
|      1 |      1 | 2019-01-09  12:43:00 AM |   1789 |
|      2 |      1 | 2019-01-09  11:35:00 AM |   1048 |
|      3 |      1 | 2019-01-09  9:22:00 AM  |    900 |
|      4 |      1 | 2019-01-09  12:43:00 AM |   1789 |
|      5 |      1 | 2019-01-09  11:35:00 AM |   1048 |
|      6 |      1 | 2019-01-09  9:22:00 AM  |    900 |
|      7 |      1 | 2019-01-09  12:43:00 AM |   1789 |
|      8 |      1 | 2019-01-09  11:35:00 AM |   1048 |
|      9 |      2 | 2019-01-17  12:05:00 AM |    552 |
|     10 |      2 | 2019-01-24  12:08:00 AM |    512 |
|     11 |      2 | 2019-01-27  5:13:00 PM  |      0 |
+--------+--------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Current Result

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| UserId | Username | Value |
+--------+----------+-------+
|      1 | JaneDoe  |  5367 |
|      2 | JohnDoe  |   552 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

Expected Result

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| UserId | Username | Value |
+--------+----------+-------+
|      1 | JaneDoe  |  3737 |
|      2 | JohnDoe  |  1064 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I was able to get the expected result with the following statement by selecting the `SUM` from a subquery and hardcoding the `UserId`.

```
SELECT SUM(`x`.`Points`) FROM
(SELECT `Points`
    FROM `Game`
    WHERE `Game`.`UserId` = 1 AND
    `Game`.`StartDate` > STR_TO_DATE('01/09/2019', '%m/%d/%Y') AND `Game`.`StartDate` < STR_TO_DATE('02/09/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
    GROUP BY `Game`.`StartDate`
    ORDER BY `Game`.`Points` ASC) AS `x`;
```

When I try to put that statement in a subquery like in the following statement, I get this error message `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'User.UserId' in 'where clause'`. I'm getting this error because the `UserId` isn't visible in the second subquery.

```
SELECT `User`.`UserId`, `User`.`Username`,
        (SELECT SUM(`x`.`Points`) FROM (SELECT `Game`.`Points`
            FROM `Game`
            WHERE `Game`.`UserId` = `User`.`UserId` AND
            `Game`.`StartDate` > STR_TO_DATE('01/09/2019', '%m/%d/%Y') AND `Game`.`StartDate` < STR_TO_DATE('02/09/2019', '%m/%d/%Y')
            GROUP BY `Game`.`StartDate`
            ORDER BY `Game`.`Points` DESC) AS `x`
        ) AS `Value`
    FROM `User`
    ORDER BY `Value` DESC, `User`.`Username` ASC;
```

Comment: What's procedural about this?

Comment: @Strawberry This isn't the only statements that will be in the stored procedure.

Comment: Hm, maybe see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.  Sample input?  Sample output?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Eric I've edited my question to add samples as you requested.

Comment: Does this mach your question...? https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/3688648

Comment: @Felk Yes, the link helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the query to use `LEFT JOIN` on `Game`. I also added `GROUP BY 'Game'.'UserId', 'Game'.'StartDate'` and `GROUP BY 'User'.'UserId'`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `spGetPoints`(
    IN _StartDate DATETIME,
    IN _EndDate DATETIME,
    IN _Limit INT,
    IN _Offset INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT `User`.`UserId`, `User`.`Username`,
        SUM(`Game`.`Points`) AS `Value`
        FROM `User`
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM `Game` 
            WHERE `Game`.`StartDate` > _StartDate AND `Game`.`StartDate` < _EndDate
            GROUP BY `Game`.`UserId`, `Game`.`StartDate`
            ORDER BY `Game`.`Points`
        ) AS `Game` ON `User`.`UserId` = `Game`.`UserId`
        GROUP BY `User`.`UserId`
        ORDER BY `Value` DESC, `User`.`Username` ASC
        LIMIT _Limit OFFSET _Offset;
END
```

This link also helped. [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/3688648)